# Vue 2.0 Webpack "need approprate loader" for template in .vue files

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2, vue-loader

I was having a hard time figuring out some features in with a bootstrapped `vue-cli` project. I didn't want to use the `webpack-dev-server` because I wanted to use my own express app to serve the `index.html` file and the `build.js` file. So I decided to set up Vue 2.0 with Webpack from scratch.

I've hit an error while running `webpack`,

```
ERROR in ./src/App.vue
Module parse failed: C:\node\aaaaa\customer\src\App.vue Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template lang="html">
|   <div id="app">
|     <h1>This is from App.vue</h1>
 @ ./src/main.js 2:0-27
```

I keep getting this error and by the looks of it the `vue-loader` isn't taking care of requiring in the `App.vue` which was required from `main.js`. I've come across `vue-html-loader` on another SO answer but I guess that was for an older version of Vue.

```
my-project
├──src
|  ├──App.vue
|  ├──main.js
├──node_modules
├──package.json
├──webpack.config.js
```

The `App.vue` and `main.js` remain the same from the `vue-cli` version.

This is my `package.json` dependencies, which differs from the original vue-cli dependencies by not installing `webpack-dev-server`, `cross-env` and `file-loader`.

```
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
  "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
  "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
  "vue-loader": "^10.0.0",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.0",
  "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25"
}
```

My `webpack.config.js` doesn't contain some parts from the vue-cli version which I thought was unnecessary.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        include: './src',
        options: {
          // vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: './src',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: { //https://github.com/babel/babel-loader
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The `webpack.config.js` file from the `vue-cli` project is:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          // vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. If you could direct me to a place where I could learn to use the `vue-cli` scaffolded project and `express` together without `webpack-dev-server`, that would be great!

Comment: Not an answer but you don't have to go without `webpack-dev-server`, rather, you can config express to serve compiled static files and make the frontend dev server proxy express's server, so you won't miss the nice features like watch-and-recompile.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 That's exactly what I ended up doing, and that's even better! Right now for development I use webpack-dev-server and use my Express API with the 'Allow-Cross-Origin' headers. In production, I will use the API itself to send the files, so I can do without the headers :) Thanks for commenting :)

Comment: Are you using the "proxy" I suggested or not? If you are, you shouldn't have CORS issue since both files and API results will "come from" the dev server. Just to make sure you are getting the "proxy" way right, if you didn't add that, as long as you remember to remove the headers, it's fine too.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 I can't serve the 'front-end' build.js since webpack-dev-server uses memory to store and serve files, unlike the express api which requires access to a dist folder which should contain the build.js. I can do "npm run build" in a vue-cli project which builds for production and creates a dist folder with the build.js which my express can send to the browser. But this just means 'building' again and again. This was the problem I initially faced and that is why I set out to set up vue from scratch without webpack-dev-server. Hence, I resorted to using the CORS headers temporarily.